# How to determine whether a byte array contains hashed data

Tags: encryption, hmacsha1, pbkdf2

Is it possible to determine whether a byte array contains data hashed with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1? Is there a pattern that could help?

Comment: The function you name is not a form of encryption but rather a password-based key derivation function. If no particular identifier or such is prepended to the data (which is rather implementation-specific) then the output of this function will look like random data. If the data does not appear to be random, it is probably no hash generated with this; if it does, you have no way of determining where the random data came from (unless you can guess the password that was supposed to be hashed by this function).

Comment: Oh, I forgot one thing: SHA-1 hashes (and thus also the output of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1) are 160 bits long. If the array does not consist of exactly 20 bytes (and there is nothing extra prepended or appended to it), you can be sure it is not such a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below is how I solved the issue in Scala:

```
class Password(value: String, salt: Option[String]) {

  private final val IterationCount = 2048
  private final val KeyLength = 256
  private final val SaltLength = KeyLength / 8

  ...

  def hash = {
    val zalt = if (salt.isDefined)
      salt.get.getBytes(DefaultCharset)
    else 
      SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(SaltLength)

    val secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
    val secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(
      new PBEKeySpec(value.toCharArray, zalt, IterationCount, KeyLength)
    )

    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2 + KeyLength)
    byteBuffer.putShort(KeyLength)
    byteBuffer.put(secretKey.getEncoded)

    new Password(
      Base64.encodeBase64String(byteBuffer.array),
      Some(new String(zalt, DefaultCharset))
    )
  }

  def isHashed = Base64.decodeBase64(value).length > KeyLength
}
```

The length of the key is prepended to the encoded hash... and to determine whether or not the current `Password` instance is hashed I just check the length of the whole buffer – the complete source code is available [here](https://github.com/gokillo/brix/blob/master/brix-corelib/src/main/scala/brix/security/Password.scala).